# How do I know when to use the predicative?

Tags: grammar

The predicative is a part of a sentence which is neither subject, nor object, nor verb, nor preposition term. Yet it relates to the verb somehow. I am not sure if the predicative is exactly the same as indirect object. Some examples are

> Ili estas **lacaj**
>
> Ĝi farbas la domon **ruĝa**

However, it can also be more complicated (examples taken from tekstaro)

> Oni petis lin **solvi la disputon**
>
> Ĉi tiuj konoj igis ilin **observi la astrojn**

Are there some rules for which verbs can use the predicative? Is there some default meaning of the predicative?

Comment: The second set of examples are what I would call an infinitive complement; a non-finite clause depending on the matrix verb (_petis_ in the first case). But there are many attempts at describing grammatical structure, and they're often using incompatible terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to lump everything you describe here together, nor to think of it in terms of grammatical terminology. Rather, I like to think of it in terms of patterns. As a result, it's a lot easier to consider specific examples than to come up with general rules.

For example, consider the sentence you listed:

- Li farbas la domon ruĝa.

In this example "ruĝa" describes the state of the house. However, consider a similar sentence:

- Li farbas la domon sola.

This could be understood with "sola" describing "li". That is, he's painting the house alone.

Basically, learn a few of the patterns, and if there's any concern about your sentence not being clear, try rewording it.

There's a little more information in PMEG [here](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/sen/perverba_priskribo.html).

Comment: The second sentence should IIUC use "sole" rather than "sola".

Comment: I would request not making "IIUC" comments here. Please try to understand correctly, then comment. This is supposed to be a forum for expert advice. I chose the word *solaj* on purpose. I invite you to read through the PMEG article linked in my answer above, as well as the article linked here --- http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortoj/uzo.html